# AES implementation for BlackBerry and iPhone

Tags: iphone, encryption, blackberry, aes

How to implement AES in BlackBerry and iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RIM knowedge base article [How to - Use Basic Encryption](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800779/How_to_-_Use_Basic_Encryption.html?nodeid=800640&vernum=0), explains how to implement AES encryption using the Blackberry API.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Blackberry, but Google revealed [this class for the iPhone](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/strong-encryption-for-cocoa-cocoa-touch.html) which can encrypt NSData objects using AES, and supports NSFileManager too.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [BouncyCastle](http://bouncycastle.org/java.html) for a JavaME implementation of many common crypto algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

You could look in CommonCrypto library, and CryptoExercise sample app in Apple developer portal.